# How to get the arxiv paper url

Tags: python, pdf, langchain, arxiv

In currently working on the project for which I'm trying to connect `arxiv` with `langchain`. I figured out how to load documenmts on the disc from the arxive search:

```py
paper = arxiv.Search(query=paper_id, max_results=1)
paper.download_pdf()
```

But I want to connect that with `langchain.document_loaders` (for example `PyPDFDirectoryLoader` or something like it) in order to have this `PDF` as a variable. For that I assume I need to have a URL of the paper which I couldn't figure out how to get.

If you have any thoughts or you tired to do it yourself let me know.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: LangChain has a built-in [ArxivLoader](https://python.langchain.com/docs/integrations/document_loaders/arxiv).